# Debian: Syslog - Create a own log file

Tags: php, debian, syslog

I use PHP and want to log some functions of my script. I want to use syslog. I thought i can just add a new line in the /etc/rsyslog.conf file:
`application.*                      -/var/log/application.log`

and log it like this with PHP:

```
define_syslog_variables();
openlog("upload", LOG_PID, LOG_APPLICATION);
syslog(LOG_DEBUG, "Test");
closelog();
```

but it don't work. There is no file called application.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues come to my mind regarding your problem:

# 1
Have you restarted the sysklogd server after adding your application to the /etc/rsyslog.conf?

```
/etc/init.d/sysklogd restart
```

# 2
How is your php configured to log?

```
  -> php.ini   
  error_log = syslog
```

Comment: What linux distribution are you using?

Comment: `
Linux version 2.6.32-5-amd64 (Debian 2.6.32-48squeeze1) (dannf@debian.org) (gcc version 4.3.5 (Debian 4.3.5-4) )`

Comment: Then try: sudo service rsyslogd restart because "... Debian uses rsyslog instead of sysklogd by default" found here http://wiki.debian.org/Rsyslog :)

Comment: command not found. This commands are used for ubuntu. And /etc/init.d/rsyslog can be found but not restart.

Comment: Finaly :D I had to install rsyslog, but the configfile was already there. whatever. thanks :)